# How to setup a shopping based UI for different screen sizes in unity?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, uiview

I am trying to set up a shopping based UI for different screen sizes.In the canvas settings inside the Inspector I have given a reference resolution of 750 x 1334(Iphone 6)

UI scale mode - Scale with screen size
 Match(Width-Height) - 0.5 (Which I change to one can see them in the images)

Somehow I placed the Images and text according to given design.It looks ok in the Iphone resolution.But in Ipad the buttons and text gets mixed up.
Now I change the Match(Width-Height) - 1 .The result is it looks okay but in the ipad view it looks small and there is plenty of space along the two sides.
How to get a matching view/look for all the different screen sizes.

Images are given below
[image: Match given as 0.5]

[image: Match given as 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, u don't need to change the match size.

what u actually have to use are anchors. If u use anchors no matter how the size of the screen changes the UI element will resize with it.

see this video from unity officials. It will definitely solve ur issue.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FeheZqu85WI&list=PLX2vGYjWbI0Qp0sD8_RKgbWul7z_eyNAv&index=2

thank you.
U can accept this answer if this solves ur issue.

Comment: The images looks stretched in width when I set customised anchors for ipad(2228 x 1668 resolution) and looks stretched in height when I set customised anchors for iphone(750 x 1338).

Comment: Dont stretch anchor over the image just pin it at the center of the image then it wont strech.

Comment: avoid customized anchor?

Comment: What??. I mean u should put the anchor inside the image and dont strech the anchor by doing that the image will move according to image and will not size. Try this once.

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-avoid-images-looking-stretched-when-using-customized-anchors.642559/

Comment: Potrait and landscape..How will that affect the images...potrait mode really narrows the width.

Comment: I dont have my laptop now, when i will reach home i will send u a screenshot on which i will place an anchor. U try placing the anchor like that and see if that help.

Comment: Try placing the anchor at the center of the image and put anchor in such a way that all the 4 triangle of the anchor touch each other that is they should be stretched in any axis by doing so the image will move but will not resize if the screen resize.

Comment: But I want buttons and images to resize according to screen sizes

Comment: If u want to resize Then u have to put the anchor around the image like all triangle of the anchor at all corner of the image. Also tick preserves aspect ratio in image component in unity inspector and if stretching anchor over the image is reuslting in image getting too stretched try anchoring anchor inside the image but dont stretch all over the image just stretch a little for eg is image is a rectangle of 3*6 then make anchor as 1*2 and pls put anchor inside that image.

Comment: That is what I tried...but not getting the feel I want..Let me chk with Aspect Ratio Fitter...